# $X\neq \varnothing$ topological space that is Compact and Haussdorf without an isolated elements.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

$X\neq \varnothing$ topological space that is Compact and Haussdorf without an isolated elements.
 I need to proof that for Every open subset $U \subset X $ and for every $x\in X$  exist open subset $V\subset X $ such that $V\subset U$  but  $x\not \in \overline V$

I tried to take 2 points one x and the second y while U is some open neighberhood of y that $x\not\in U$ but because Haussdorf x have neighborhood S such that $S\bigcap U \neq \varnothing$ I stucked here...

Comment: Well, if $x\in\overline U$, then it is obvious that no such $V$ exists.

Comment: The statement becomes correct if $U$ is assumed to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U\subseteq X$ be open, $x\in X$. Since $X$ does not have isolated points then in particular every open subset has at least two points and thus there exists $y\in U$ such that $y\neq x$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff then $x$ and $y$ can be separated by two open neighbourhoods, say $V_x, V_y$. Obviously $x\not\in \overline{V_y}$ because $\overline{V_y}\subseteq X\backslash V_x$.

Put $V:=V_y\cap U$. Then $V\subseteq U$ and $x\not\in\overline{V}\subseteq\overline{V_y}$.

Side note: I don't see how compactness plays a role here.